# Load bootstrap Modal on first visit to site

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a subscription box that activates the first time you visit the website.

At the moment the subscription modal doesnt load when you first visit the site and I can't figure out why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).load(function(){
         // load the overlay
        if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
            var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
            var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
            document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
            jQuery.modal({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#myModal"});
        }
    });
</script>
```

I can load the modal by click a link but I need to automatically popup when a user first visits. Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you're referring to:

```
jQuery('#myModal')
```

And later you are referring to:

```
jQuery('.myModal')
```

Is it a class or an id? Probably that is your mistake.

On a side-note, you may wish to specify the language-attribute on your script tag.

Comment: I've made some changes to the code but it still doesn't load when the site is first visited. I've cleared cache and cookies but nothing - Still trying to fix!

Comment: Thanks my friend I got it to work with jQuery(window).load(function() instead of jQuery(document).ready(function()

Answer (score 0):

There is no href option to the modal function in bootstrap. What you want to do is target the actual modal element and then call the modal function on it to activate it as a modal. Like so;

```
 jQuery('#myModal').modal(options)
```

Check out the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) for available options

Also, example jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n9bvJ/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The only problem is that the Modal will activate whenever the page is loaded (I am using it for the homepage). I need to find way that it only loads once then sets the cookie so if the user navigates to the homepage again the modal won't load until the cookie has expired.

Comment: I haven't used cookies much, but at first glance your logic seem ok. As long as the browser allows cookies, that is?
I assumed the problem was to programmatically trigger the modal, and meant for you to change the last line of code (the jQuery.modal line) with my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        $('#flag').trigger('click');
     $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    }

});
```

This is my script for you.

Comment: <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="flag"></div>   this is the div which is auto click @vipin